# Aborting/resuming state snapshots all the time

Tags: go-ethereum

I get this behaviour after updating to 1.10.

Is this normal? -  I mean, aborting & resuming "state snapshot generation" all the time.  Please feel free to explain in more depth what's going on.

```
INFO [03-06|11:05:02.052] Imported new chain segment               blocks=6       txs=1253      mgas=74.927  elapsed=8.221s      mgasps=9.114  number=11610792 hash="5062e6…7a58c2" age=1mo3w6d dirty=500.51MiB
INFO [03-06|11:05:03.831] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="d156fd…3257a7" at="000d56…d9f93b" accounts=23177 slots=11741 storage=1.99MiB    elapsed=3m18.858s   eta=271h19m46.37s
INFO [03-06|11:05:03.831] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="351f41…5727a7" at="000d56…d9f93b" accounts=23177 slots=11741 storage=1.99MiB    elapsed=3m18.858s   eta=271h19m46.37s
INFO [03-06|11:05:04.862] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="351f41…5727a7" at="000d77…3be2c3" accounts=23420 slots=11900 storage=2.01MiB    elapsed=3m19.890s   eta=270h11m12.136s
INFO [03-06|11:05:04.890] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="9f3e62…3b67e8" at="000d77…3be2c3" accounts=23420 slots=11900 storage=2.01MiB    elapsed=3m19.917s   eta=270h13m23.518s
INFO [03-06|11:05:06.048] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="9f3e62…3b67e8" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="1169fb…7e1aaf" accounts=23733 slots=12049 storage=2.04MiB    elapsed=3m21.076s   eta=268h21m53.98s
INFO [03-06|11:05:06.049] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="f8af5d…9b0b94" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="1169fb…7e1aaf" accounts=23733 slots=12049 storage=2.04MiB    elapsed=3m21.076s   eta=268h21m53.98s
INFO [03-06|11:05:06.085] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="f8af5d…9b0b94" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="11abfc…57da2d" accounts=23733 slots=12052 storage=2.04MiB    elapsed=3m21.112s   eta=268h24m46.949s
INFO [03-06|11:05:06.085] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="e20aa1…b98f13" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="11abfc…57da2d" accounts=23733 slots=12052 storage=2.04MiB    elapsed=3m21.113s   eta=268h24m51.754s
INFO [03-06|11:05:07.034] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="e20aa1…b98f13" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="72b225…e62036" accounts=23733 slots=12484 storage=2.07MiB    elapsed=3m22.061s   eta=269h40m46.606s
INFO [03-06|11:05:07.034] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="2fe2af…e3d891" in="000da3…dc8d8f" at="72b225…e62036" accounts=23733 slots=12484 storage=2.07MiB    elapsed=3m22.061s   eta=269h40m46.606s
INFO [03-06|11:05:09.935] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="2fe2af…e3d891" at="000da8…474ad8" accounts=23766 slots=13045 storage=2.11MiB    elapsed=3m24.962s   eta=273h5m36.859s
INFO [03-06|11:05:09.967] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="e2b55c…067ab7" at="000da8…474ad8" accounts=23766 slots=13045 storage=2.11MiB    elapsed=3m24.995s   eta=273h8m15.149s
INFO [03-06|11:05:09.984] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6026604 txs=277134736 total=9259841 elapsed=51m29.443s
INFO [03-06|11:05:11.490] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="e2b55c…067ab7" at="000dde…501101" accounts=24126 slots=13099 storage=2.13MiB    elapsed=3m26.517s   eta=271h2m42.627s
INFO [03-06|11:05:11.490] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="05846e…1ad275" at="000dde…501101" accounts=24126 slots=13099 storage=2.13MiB    elapsed=3m26.518s   eta=271h2m47.351s
INFO [03-06|11:05:11.519] Imported new chain segment               blocks=7       txs=1052      mgas=74.891  elapsed=9.466s      mgasps=7.911  number=11610799 hash="771b87…319df2" age=1mo3w6d dirty=499.42MiB
INFO [03-06|11:05:12.180] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="05846e…1ad275" at="000df5…0a06b8" accounts=24291 slots=13129 storage=2.14MiB    elapsed=3m27.207s   eta=270h12m12.087s
INFO [03-06|11:05:12.180] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="1b1675…732bb6" at="000df5…0a06b8" accounts=24291 slots=13129 storage=2.14MiB    elapsed=3m27.207s   eta=270h12m12.087s
INFO [03-06|11:05:18.573] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6030266 txs=277592656 total=9259841 elapsed=51m38.032s
INFO [03-06|11:05:24.740] Generating state snapshot                root="1b1675…732bb6" at="000e05…4b8089" accounts=24413 slots=13151 storage=2.15MiB    elapsed=3m39.768s   eta=285h15m55.614s
INFO [03-06|11:05:26.621] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6032623 txs=277896114 total=9259841 elapsed=51m46.080s
INFO [03-06|11:05:30.487] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="1b1675…732bb6" at="000e1a…d593aa" accounts=24544 slots=13175 storage=2.16MiB    elapsed=3m45.514s   eta=290h59m47.374s
INFO [03-06|11:05:30.487] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="840d44…db1b11" at="000e1a…d593aa" accounts=24544 slots=13175 storage=2.16MiB    elapsed=3m45.514s   eta=290h59m47.374s
INFO [03-06|11:05:30.507] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2       txs=214       mgas=24.911  elapsed=18.988s     mgasps=1.312  number=11610801 hash="79a5ea…4f4792" age=1mo3w6d dirty=499.38MiB
INFO [03-06|11:05:34.695] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6036390 txs=278351823 total=9259841 elapsed=51m54.154s
INFO [03-06|11:05:38.628] Generating state snapshot                root="840d44…db1b11" at="000e1b…e88c20" accounts=24549 slots=13176 storage=2.16MiB    elapsed=3m53.655s   eta=301h27m36.229s
INFO [03-06|11:05:42.895] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6037082 txs=278448337 total=9259841 elapsed=52m2.354s
INFO [03-06|11:05:46.666] Generating state snapshot                root="840d44…db1b11" at="000e1f…76833d" accounts=24571 slots=13187 storage=2.16MiB    elapsed=4m1.693s    eta=311h30m47.114s
INFO [03-06|11:05:51.324] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6041000 txs=279004882 total=9259841 elapsed=52m10.783s
INFO [03-06|11:05:54.221] Aborting state snapshot generation       root="840d44…db1b11" at="000e3a…f5c14f" accounts=24751 slots=13255 storage=2.18MiB    elapsed=4m9.248s    eta=318h47m44.344s
INFO [03-06|11:05:54.221] Resuming state snapshot generation       root="406f67…4791ab" at="000e3a…f5c14f" accounts=24751 slots=13255 storage=2.18MiB    elapsed=4m9.249s    eta=318h47m48.949s
INFO [03-06|11:05:54.270] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1       txs=294       mgas=12.464  elapsed=23.762s     mgasps=0.525  number=11610802 hash="4527f2…7eb432" age=1mo3w6d dirty=499.85MiB
INFO [03-06|11:05:59.205] Deep froze chain segment                 blocks=14      elapsed=1.350s      number=11520802 hash="6c1ca1…406b17"
INFO [03-06|11:05:59.434] Unindexing transactions                  blocks=6047654 txs=279787357 total=9259841 elapsed=52m18.893s
INFO [03-06|11:06:02.314] Generating state snapshot                root="406f67…4791ab" at="000e56…d9478b" accounts=24941 slots=13301 storage=2.19MiB    elapsed=4m17.341s   eta=326h41m33.212s
```

Answer (score 4):

I shot too fast.. now I found found [geth 1.10 release notes](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.10.0) and just used "--snapshot=false".

Sorry for the spam.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal and desired behavior. It is generating snapshot “in between blocks” to not interfere with node operations.

Don’t be afraid, turn that back on and let it generate. Should take 3-4 days on mainstream SATA ssd, 1 day on fast SSD.

Comment: you don't need snapshots if you are syncing an archival node, so do intefere and turn it off